# Trying to use NGINX as reverse proxy into private network

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, jupyterhub, proxmox

I currently have a cluster of Proxmox machines setup on a private network that connect to the internet through an Ubuntu machine as a gateway. I have a VM on my Proxmox cluster that's running Jupyter Hub, but it is only accessible from within the private network.

I would like to setup NGINX on my Ubuntu gateway server to let me access the Jupyter Hub VM from outside the network by setting up a reverse proxy. Is this the type of thing that NGINX is used for? If so, where would I start? If not, how would I accomplish this?

I've tried setting proxy_pass in NGINX to the IP of the Jupyter Hub VM, but I keep getting site is unavailable.